# How to ignore the next int from standard input

Tags: c++, cin

Suppose I want to disregard the next `int` from standard input. I can obviously do this

```
int a;
std::cin >> a;
// do nothing with a
```

but is it possible without creating a useless variable?

Comment: You can probable use ignore up to the next space something like `cin.ignore(INT_MAX,' ')` assuming you have other values separated by space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX, ' '); // if ' ' is after the integer
```